# .htaccess: redirecting to HTTPS main domain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have this really weird problem which I've already spent a lot of time investigating, but failed to find a solution.

Basically, I have a few domains parked in the server, but for simplicity, let's assume just 2 domains:

1. example.co.nz (main)
2. example.com

I have 2 requirements I'd like to satisfy:

- a) I want all traffic from (2) redirected to (1)
- b) I want all HTTP traffic to be redirected to HTTPS

So basically, in one sentence, I want all traffic to simply go to https://www.example.co.nz no matter what URL patterns I type into the location bar.

---

I have written a .htaccess file in the root like this:

```
SetEnv TZ

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.co\.nz
    RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.co.nz/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(system|lib)(.*)$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

---

The following works:

- http://www.example.co.nz
- https://www.example.co.nz
- http://www.example.com

The following does not get redirected:

- https://www.example.com

---

- Would anyone happen to have any ideas why this is happening?

I was wondering if this is related to my htaccess or the server itself.

Any help would be high appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.

The redirect is actually working. You get a warning about the certificate at https://www.example.com when you attempt to visit the website. Once you accept the warning, you are redirected to https://www.example.co.nz/.

That is because the SSL check is applied before the .htaccess rewrites. Since there is no certificate installed for www.example.com, you get a warning.

The only way around that is to install an SSL certificate for www.example.com as well.

Comment: That is slight wrong, the check applies because YOU are attempting to access HTTPS on a domain name without a valid certificate, once the user accepts that, then it tries to access the domain with the valid certificate. To put it simple, they are 2 different requests during the process.

Comment: What I mentioned is exactly what you're saying.  So it is correct indeed.

Comment: Can you please remove the -1, because that was exactly the problem and it is correct: "SSL check is applied before the .htaccess rewrites".